# Why 2>/dev/null isnt't working?

Tags: bash, shell-script, sudo

I want to ask the user for sudo password at the beggining of my script and then make a test if this password is correct before running the rest of the script.

So after searching a while, I got this test script:

```
SUDO_PWD=whatever
sudo -k   # <- So I can test it
echo $SUDO_PWD | sudo -Svp '' 2>/dev/null 
sudo_response=$(SUDO_ASKPASS=/bin/false sudo -A whoami @>/dev/null) 
if [ "$sudo_response" = "root" ]; then 
    echo "sudo" 
else  
    echo "no sudo" 
fi
```

But both messages appear in console even with @>/dev/null redirection. Why ?

Comment: Do you realize that `echo $SUDO_PWD` will show the password to anyone and everyone able to run `ps`?!?!

Comment: Would it not be easier to let the user run your script with `sudo`? That way it's not you and your script that is asking the user for their password and storing it in a variable, but `sudo`.

Comment: What do you think `@>/dev/null` does, and for which shell?

Comment: @AndrewHenle not in this case. I've added an answer with the complete script. Run it and you'll see. The pipe redirects echo output to sudo command and it's not shown in the terminal. I also tested for some functionality I may not be aware of with `sleep infinity` in the end and `watch ps -eF | grep <mysudopassword>` and it didn't show anything. If there some ps option that may expose the password, please let me know.  :)

Comment: @Kusalananda it's easier. Mine is prettier. LOL :D

Comment: @roaima I think that `@> /dev/null` should redirect all outputs (error and stdout) to `/dev/null`. Isn't that it ?

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira I think you're thinking of `&>`.

Comment: @Kusalananda You're correct. I mixed up @ and &. Thanks for pointing that up.

Comment: NelsonTeixeira indeed just as Kusalanander wrote, you need `&>` not `@>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to not have any output (ie. no std output & no errors), you need to use redirections like that:

```bash
your_command > /dev/null 2>&1
your_command &> /dev/null
```

For showing only errors and discard standard output:

```bash
your_command > /dev/null
```

And to show only standard output and discard errors:

```bash
your_command 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks. I could make it work with your explanation :)

Comment: I made some edits to clarify your answer. It wasn't imediately obvious to me. Let's see if other people users aprove my edit. :)

Comment: Yes no problem, thanks for your clarifications. I'm happy this helps you !

Answer (score 0):

In case someone gets interested in the final version of the check sudo password script, I'll leave it here:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Informe superuser password:"
. getpass.sh
echo ""
sudo -k
echo $PASSWORD | sudo -Svp '' 2> /dev/null
SUDO_ANSWER=$(SUDO_ASKPASS=/bin/false sudo -A whoami 2> /dev/null)
if [ "$SUDO_ANSWER" != "root" ]; then
    echo "Invalid superuser password. Exiting."
    exit
fi
echo "Sudo password correct. Excuting rest of the script."
```

`getpass.sh` is a bash script I got a long time ago in the internet, that gets a password in the terminal echoing asterisks instead of chars. For the sake of completeness I'll leave the code here:

```
#!/bin/bash
stty -echo
CHARCOUNT=0
while IFS= read -p "$PROMPT" -r -s -n 1 CHAR
do
    # Enter - accept password
    if [[ $CHAR == $'\0' ]] ; then
        break
    fi
    # Backspace
    if [[ $CHAR == $'\177' ]] ; then
        if [ $CHARCOUNT -gt 0 ] ; then
            CHARCOUNT=$((CHARCOUNT-1))
            PROMPT=$'\b \b'
            PASSWORD="${PASSWORD%?}"
        else
            PROMPT=''
        fi
    else
        CHARCOUNT=$((CHARCOUNT+1))
        PROMPT='*'
        PASSWORD+="$CHAR"
    fi
done
PROMPT=""
stty echo
```

Comment: Your own question is "why?". This answer does not answer the question.